# Combine two separate wp queries into one single query for search

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a search bar on my category page which will allow the search of either the product title (custom post type) or a taxonomy of brand. I can get both of these to work independently, passing in either arguments to the WP_Query, however if I attempt to array merge them both together, neither work.

What I have is:

```
$search = sanitize_text_field($_POST['productsearch']);

$post_category = $_POST['post_cat'];

$cats = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'productscat',
    'field' => 'id',
    'key' => 'name',
    'terms' => $post_category,
);


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products', //custom post type
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    's' => $search,
    'tax_query' => $cats,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'products', //custom post type
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $search,
        ),

    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$merged = array_merge($args, $args2);
$search_query = new WP_Query($merged);


if ($search_query->have_posts()) :
```

And so on with the loop; So what am I missing with the merge arguments?

Essentially i am using `'s' => $search`  only in one of the arrays to search the post name, which I do not need (or believe i need) in the brands taxonomy array

Answer (score 1):

You can combine queries like this. You can add multiple `tax_query`.

```
$search = sanitize_text_field($_POST['productsearch']);

$post_category = $_POST['post_cat'];

$args2 = array(
    'post_type'      => 'products', //custom post type
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    's'              => $search,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $search
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'productscat',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $post_category
        )

    )
);

$search_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );

if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) :

endif;
```

Comment: Ah, but I believe the issue is i'm passing in  's' as $search - which only works for searching the product/post name, and not the brand, hence the 2 separate arrays, one using 's' and one not